# In Pandas, how to create a unique ID based on the combination of many columns?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a very large dataset, that looks like

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'B': ['john smith', 'john doe', 'adam smith', 'john doe', np.nan], 'C': ['indiana jones', 'duck mc duck', 'batman','duck mc duck',np.nan]})

df
Out[173]: 
            B              C
0  john smith  indiana jones
1    john doe   duck mc duck
2  adam smith         batman
3    john doe   duck mc duck
4         NaN            NaN
```

I need to create a ID variable, that is unique for every B-C combination. That is, the output should be

```
            B              C   ID
0  john smith  indiana jones   1
1    john doe   duck mc duck   2
2  adam smith         batman   3
3    john doe   duck mc duck   2 
4         NaN            NaN   0
```

I actually dont care about whether the index starts at zero or not, and whether the value for the missing columns is 0 or any other number. I just want something fast, that does not take a lot of memory and can be sorted quickly.
I use:

```
df['combined_id']=(df.B+df.C).rank(method='dense')
```

but the output is `float64` and takes a lot of memory. Can we do better?
Thanks!

Comment: it's float because of the presence of `NaN` without the `NaN` values you can cast to `int` using `astype`

Comment: ohhh ok thanks! I didnt know that. so should I run `fillna()` before?

Comment: It's your decision, either fill them or drop the row

Comment: Aside: using `df.B + df.C` is asking for trouble because "ABC" is"AB"+"C" and "A" + "BC".

Comment: very, very good point indeed. but is there something better?

Comment: You can insert a special character (e.g. double underscore) between the two to reduce the probability of that occurring, e.g. `df.B + "__" + df.C`

Comment: smart indeed. thanks alexander

Comment: the really nice thing about this is that eveything happens on the fly. no nee d to actually generate these super long strings

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you can use [`factorize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.factorize.html):

```
df['combined_id'] = pd.factorize(df.B+df.C)[0]
print df
            B              C  combined_id
0  john smith  indiana jones            0
1    john doe   duck mc duck            1
2  adam smith         batman            2
3    john doe   duck mc duck            1
4         NaN            NaN           -1
```

Answer (score 6):

Making jezrael's answer a little more general (what if the columns were not string?), you can use this compact function:

```
def make_identifier(df):
    str_id = df.apply(lambda x: '_'.join(map(str, x)), axis=1)
    return pd.factorize(str_id)[0]

df['combined_id'] = make_identifier(df[['B','C']])
```

Answer (score 0):

jezrael's answer is great. But since this is for multiple columns, I prefer to use [.ngroup()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.ngroup.html) since this way NaN could remain NaN.

```
df['combined_id'] = df.groupby(['B', 'C'], sort = False).ngroup()
df
```

[image]