# Creating a unique id based on combinations of columns (ignoring order)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

## Scenario

Imagine a dataset that is the result of some process. The dataset contains two id columns, `id1` and `id2`, that represent where parts of the data came from in preceding process. The two id columns can be int or string. I want to create a unique id based on the ids present in **both** of these id columns. **However, the ordering of ids is not important**. For example:

`id1 == A` and `id2 == NaN` is the same as `id1 == NaN` and `id2==A` because the only 'real' id present is `A`. The id value could be a single letter, number, or string(s).

## Test data

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import numpy as np
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'id1': ['A', np.nan, 'A', 'B'], 'id2': [np.nan, 'B', 'B', 'A']})
>>> df
   id1  id2
0    A  NaN
1  NaN    B
2    B    B
3    B    A
```

## Core question

How can I use pandas and numpy functions to create a single unique id based on the combinations of id1 and id2 when ordering is not important?

## Other relevant answers

[In Pandas, how to create a unique ID based on the combination of many columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36646923/in-pandas-how-to-create-a-unique-id-based-on-the-combination-of-many-columns)

[Grouping by multiple columns to find duplicate rows pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46640945/grouping-by-multiple-columns-to-find-duplicate-rows-pandas)

## Things I've tried

- Coercing id1 and id2 to strings, combining, sorting, and dropping duplicates (works but is messy)
- `pd.factorize`: seems better than above but still requires a combination and sorting of id1 and id2

## Desired output

```
>>> df
   id1  id2  combined_id
0    A  NaN  A
1  NaN    B  B
2    A    B  AB
3    B    A  AB
4  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Comment: What about `B A` will that be `AB` also since ordering is not important or will it be `BA`?

Comment: @onyambu thanks for your response! Yes, `B A` should also become `AB`.

Comment: @whatwhatWHAT is it okay to create a numerical id for the combination of both columns? for example for the givwn sample the resulting id column would be (0, 1, 2, 2, 3)

Comment: @ShubhamSharma yes, for sure! I think `pd.factorize` accomplishes this, in a sense.

Answer (score 0):

Added a row `B A` to your data

```
(df.reset_index().melt('index').dropna().sort_values('value')
   .groupby('index').agg({'value':''.join}))
 
      value
index      
0         A
1         B
2        AB
3        AB
```

Comment: Will this work for strings? E.g,. what if the `id`s are `Red Blue`, which should be the same as `Blue Red`?

Comment: @whatwhatWHAT Yes it will work for strings. Try it out

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is:

```
df['combinedid'] = df['id1']+ df['id2']
```

Result:

|  | id1 | id2 | combinedid |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | A |  |  |
| 1 |  | B |  |
| 2 | A | B | AB |

After you remove the **NaN** values:

```
df = df.fillna("")
df['combinedid'] = df['id1']+ df['id2']
```

Result:

|  | id1 | id2 | combinedid |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | A |  | A |
| 1 |  | B | B |
| 2 | A | B | AB |

Comment: I updated the question to show why those solutions would not work (e.g., in the case of `B A` which is equivalent to `A B`